# Google BigQuery - Subtract SUMs of a column basing on values in another column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata

Hi I need 1 query to get top 10 `country` which has largest [total(`import`) - total(`export`)] for `goods_type` medicines between 2019 - 2020.

The data sample is as below:

```
year | trading_type | country | goods_type | amount
2020   import         ABC       medicines    12345.67
2017   import         ABC       medicines    null
2019   export         DEF       foods        987.65
2018   export         ABC       foods        2345.6
2016   export         DEF       medicines    120.3
2019   export         ABC       medicines    345.67
2020   import         DEF       foods        321.04
...    ...            ...       ...          ...
```

The returned data should include `country`, `goods_type`, and the value of [total(`imports`) - total(`export`)].

I have come up with the query below, but I don't know if it's right or wrong, and I struggle to extend it to get other columns. I got an error telling `select expression column ... not grouped or aggregated...` in Google BigQuery console.

```
SELECT country, year FROM `trading_records` T    <--- error here for the year
WHERE
    T.product_type = 'medicines' AND
    (T.year = 2019 OR T.year = 2020)
GROUP BY T.country
ORDER BY (
    (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM `trading_records`
    WHERE trading_type = 'import' AND country = T.country)
    -
    (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM `trading_records`
    WHERE trading_type = 'export' AND country = T.country)
) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

I appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express this as a single query with `GROUP BY`, filtering, and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT country, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN trading_type = 'import' THEN amount ELSE - amount END) as total 
FROM data 
WHERE trading_type in ('import', 'export') AND
      goods_type = 'medicines' AND
      year >= 2019 AND
      year <= 2020
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Note that this does not include `YEAR` in the `SELECT` because it is "aggregated away".

Comment: Thank you! Your query is so neat and working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using conditional sums. For example SUM(IF(Condition, true_value, false_value). This will first evaluate your Condition. If it's True, the true_value (which in this example is the amount) will be included in the SUM. If it evaluates to False then 0 will be added to the SUM.

This will give you what you want

```sql
SELECT country, goods_type, SUM(IF(trading_type='import', amount, 0)) - SUM(IF(trading_type='export', amount, 0)) as import_minus_export
FROM `trading_records`
WHERE goods_type='medicines' AND year IN (2019, 2020)
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 2 DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are other ways but this query does what you are looking for:

```
WITH data as (
    SELECT 2020 as year, "import" as trading_type, "ABC" as country, 
                       "medicines" as goods_type, 12345.67 as amount UNION ALL
    SELECT 2019, "import", "ABC", "medicines", null UNION ALL
    SELECT 2019, "export", "DEF", "foods", 987.65 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2018, "export", "ABC", "foods", 2345.6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2016, "export", "DEF", "medicines", 120.3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2019, "export", "ABC", "medicines", 345.67 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2020, "import", "DEF", "foods", 321.04)

,agg_data as ( 
SELECT year, 
       country, 
       IF(trading_type = "import", amount, amount * -1) as total 
FROM data 
WHERE goods_type = "medicines" AND year in (2019,2020) 
)

SELECT country, SUM(total) as total 
FROM agg_data
GROUP BY country
LIMIT 1
```

You should change the last LIMIT 1 to 10

**Result:**
ABC 12000.0